# What is the format of generic returned types?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf, generics

i serialize and post generic types in wcf services and receive it as a json. the format of serialized objects `{'__type':'MyClass:#namespace', ...}`.

i use `__type` value to create key value pairs like: `MyClass:{x:y, ...}` on client side using js.

now i want to do the same thing with generic types i get from wcf services. it is appended a set of hash like numbers and chars. does anybody  know the format of the additional char set?
does it follow a specific pattern that helps me to remove it using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data contract name for generic types can be customized to remove the hash part - see [Data Contract Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731045.aspx) for more information.